# How many regular tetrahedrons of the same size can we distinguish

Tags: combinatorics

How many regular tetrahedrons of the same size can we distinguish using 4 different colours to paint all their faces? Each face can only be painted with one colour.

My solution:

- Using a single colour to colour the whole tetrahedron, we can form 4 distinct tetrahedrons, each with a different colour;
- Using two colours to colour the tetrahedron, we can choose $\binom{4}{2}$
  colour combinations. In addition, we can colour three faces with
  one colour and one face with the other colour, and vice versa, or two faces with each colour.
  totalling $6 \times 3=18$ distinct tetrahedrons;
- Using three colours to colour the tetrahedron, we can choose $\binom{4}{3}$
  colour combinations. In addition, we can choose $3$ options for
  the colour that will colour two faces, while the other two colours will be used to colour a single face each.
  used to colour a single face each, generating in this case,
  of $4\times3=12$ possibilities;
- Using the four colours, each colour will colour one face, and it will only be possible to distinguish $2$ tetrahedrons by reversing the colours of any two faces. Any two faces.

The sum of the cases results in $36$.

As the tetrahedron has 4 faces and equal sides, I was wondering if this problem could be interpreted as: how many different ways can I arrange 1, 2, 3 or 4 people on a round table with positions? If so (or something involving circular permutation and/or circular permutation with repetition) I'd like a hint on how to proceed with the solution.

Comment: I thought about painting four chairs arranged in a circle with four available colors, with each chair being painted with one color.  However, the analogy breaks down in the two chairs of one color and two chairs of another color since it matters whether chairs of the same color are adjacent or alternate.